# como puedo probar mi proycto de react.js en mi celular

Tags: reactjs

hize una pagina web en react.js pero quiero probarla desde mi celular pero no se como hacerlo y no entiendo bien la documentacion como podria porbarla desde mi celular ya que intente conectar mi celular a la misma ip de mi compu pero no funciono existe algun comando o algo para hacer una demo o probar el apk de mi proyecto de react

Comment: como apk de react? algo no me cuadra.. deberias poner el celu en la misma red que tu pc y deberias poder acceder a la misma...

Comment: ya lo intente asi estoy conectado a la misma red y no funciono

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba desde tu red local.  Ingresa desde el navegador de tu celular y te vas a:
http://192.16X.X.XX:3000
Cambia las X por los números de tú IP local.
Prueba eso o extiende la dirección del sitio con la extensión que uses.